# Function works in a notebook, but not as part of package - Message about function argument is Protected

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following code works when evaluated in a notebook:

```
Person[name_String, age_Integer] := {name, age};
Person["Jane", 30]
name = "Dick";
age = 28;
Person[name, age]
```

Output

```
{"Jane", 30}
{"Dick", 28}
```

So I put it in the following package:

### Person.m

```
BeginPackage["Person`"]

Unprotect @@ Names["Person`*"];
ClearAll @@ Names["Person`*"];

Person[name_String, age_Integer] := {name, age};

Protect @@ Names["Person`*"];

EndPackage[]
```

### Person.nb

```
Needs["Person`"];

Person["Jane", 30]

name = "Dick";
age = 28;
Person[name, age]

name1 = "Bill";
age1 = 40;
Person[name1, age1]
```

### Output

```
{"Jane", 30}
Set::wrsym: Symbol name is Protected. >>
Set::wrsym: Symbol age is Protected. >>
Person[name, age]
{"Bill", 40}
```

I don't understand why there is a protection issue using symbols name and age.  Are Person's arguments "name" and "age" being protected too?

---

celtschk's answer allowed me to see the light.  The following does not expose name and age:

```
BeginPackage["Person`"]

Unprotect @@ Names["Person`*"];
ClearAll @@ Names["Person`*"];

Person::usage = "Person";    

Begin["`Private`"]
Person[name_String, age_Integer] := {name, age};
End[]

Protect @@ Names["Person`*"];

EndPackage[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since when you define your function `Person`, the current context is `` Person` ``, *all* new identifiers are created there, even the identifiers `name` and `age` (you didn't create them before, therefore they are created at that point). Afterwards you protect everything in context `` Person` ``, including those two symbols. When you then try to assign to them, Mathematica correctly complains that they are protected.

Comment: Anyone knows how to include a backtick into inline-quoted material? (for the context name)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see how to resolve this move. 'Person[name_String, age_Integer] := {name, age};' between 'Begin["`Private`"]' and 'End[]' expose it via '::usage', then 'name' and 'age' are not exposed.

Comment: @celtschk See my edit for how to enter contexts so that the ticks show up.